# How can I get all the possible values allowed in a multi-select in my template?

Tags: channel-entries, tags, fields, multiselect

I'm using EE 3.5.3 and I have a "use-area" field (in a grid of products) that's a multi-select box.

In the template, i need to make a dropdown so you can filter the products by the use-area. Each product can have more than one use-area.

Is there a way to get the values possible for the multi-select, or do I have to hard-code them?

Answer (score 0):

If you're commited to using the multi-select than apart from a query you're going to have to do it manually.

Although, are you using a channel form on the front end? If so it shouldn't require anything more than the normal tag pair.

I recall doing something similar a while ago and ended up using Low Variables > setup a multi-select and place that in your grid then that will allow you to spit out the options.

Comment: I ended up using a channel relationship to do it.